# Call JSON-RPC using nodejs

Tags: node.js, request, json-rpc

I am trying to call json-rpc call through request module of nodejs.

json-rpc call is in following format

```
curl --user myusername --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getreceivedbyaddress", "params": ["1D1ZrZNe3JUo7ZycKEYQQiQAWd9y54F4XZ", 6] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
```

How to call such json-rpc call using **request** npm package of nodejs ??

Comment: A quick search on google revealed this tool https://curl.trillworks.com/#node, it will convert the curl command to corresponding nodeJS code using request module. The generated code is quite verbose though, use it to understand the structure and then go ahead implement your solution.

Comment: Thank you so much..Its working..you make my day..:)

Comment: Alternatively, use Wildcard Api (https://github.com/reframejs/wildcard-api).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a script that will make the call using the request module:

**index.js**

```
const request = require('request');

// User and password specified like so: node index.js username password.
let username = process.argv.length < 2 ? "default-username" : process.argv[2];
let password = process.argv.length < 3 ? "default-password" : process.argv[3];

let options = {
    url: "http://localhost:8332",
    method: "post",
    headers:
    { 
     "content-type": "text/plain"
    },
    auth: {
        user: username,
        pass: password
    },
    body: JSON.stringify( {"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id": "curltest", "method": "getreceivedbyaddress", "params": ["1D1ZrZNe3JUo7ZycKEYQQiQAWd9y54F4XZ", 6] })
};

request(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error('An error has occurred: ', error);
    } else {
        console.log('Post successful: response: ', body);
    }
});
```

And then call like so:

```
node index.js username password
```

You could also use environment variables to pass the username/password.

The --auth argument passed to Curl specifies Basic authentication (as implemented in the script)